# Split does not separate string

Tags: javascript

I need to break a string into several parts and for that I did a split, but the split doesn't break the string.
It returns an array with only one value and my string inside
["9月 28, 2021"]
I expected it to return an array with [9], [月], [28], [2021].
I think JS gets lost with the 月 character, I honestly don't know what to do.

```js
let value = "9月 28, 2021";
let result = value.split(' ');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Your string probably contains non-ASCII spaces, like full-width spaces. Regardless, splitting on `' '` would not separate `9月` anyway, neither would it remove the comma.

Comment: that is the output in my browser: `[
  "9月",
  "28,",
  "2021"
]` array with 3 items.

Comment: Does 月 mean Monday, as in you want to do something with a date? (Although the 28th of September, 2021 was a Tuesday.)

Comment: Your code works like expected. If you have any problems they do not rely on the shown code

Comment: @Andrew 9月 is "the 9th *month*", i.e. September.

Comment: @deceze Google failed me!

Comment: @deceze I believe that's it but how do I split non-ASCII spaces? Here in the browser it works, but without visual code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the expected result by spliting word boundaries `\b` in addition to spaces, and commas.

```js
let value = "9月 28, 2021";
let result = value.split(/\b[\s,]*|[\s,]*\b/g);
console.log(result);
```